# Error "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting" running a Python code

Tags: python

I'm running a python code, actually the code is running fine, but for some reason, it's printing an error on the screen.

```
#!/data/go_dl/resources/miniconda3/envs/stg01.nifi_Env/bin/python
import os
import logging
from logging import handlers
landingPath = '/data/go_dl/resources/CMM/'
logPath = '/data/go_dl/resources/CMM/'
logging.basicConfig(filename= logPath+'Log_Rename.log',filemode='w', level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(funcName)s => %(message)s')
logging.info("STARTING THE PROCESS")
logging.info("Creating the file with the list of .DAT files to be renamed")
try:
    preListFile = []
    finalListFile = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(landingPath):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('.DAT'):
                preListFile.append(landingPath+file)
    finalListFile = '\n'.join(sorted(preListFile))
    with open("listOfFiles.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(finalListFile)
    logging.info("The files to be renamed are :\n"+finalListFile)
except:
    logging.error("Error in create the list of .DAT files")

fileList = '/data/go_dl/resources/CMM/listOfFiles.txt'
MST_Prefix = 'NOKIA_CMM_MST_'
ZTN_Prefix = 'NOKIA_CMM_ZTN_'
dateValueList = []
try:
    with open(fileList,"r") as arq:
        for rowListValue  in arq.readlines():
            logging.info("rowListValue :",rowListValue)
            fileInBytes = open(rowListValue.strip(),'rb')
            fileInHexString = fileInBytes.read().hex()
            logging.info("Getting the position of the string 9009")
            searchedIndexValue = fileInHexString.find('9009')
            logging.info("Getting the date value of the file")
            fileDateValue = fileInHexString[searchedIndexValue+4:searchedIndexValue+16]
            logging.info("The file"+rowListValue+"has the DateValue :"+fileDateValue)
            logging.info("Adding 20 to the date value of the value")
            dateValueList = "20"+fileInHexString[searchedIndexValue+4:searchedIndexValue+16]
            try:
                logging.info("renaming the file : "+rowListValue)
                #os.rename(rowListValue.strip(), landingPath+MST_Prefix+dateValueList+"_"+rowListValue.strip().split("_")[-1])
            except:
                logging.error("Error in rename the file"+rowListValue)
except:
logging.error("Error starting the rename of the files")
```

That's the error appearing on the screen :

> ```
> --- Logging error ---
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/data/go_dl/resources/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1081, in emit
>     msg = self.format(record)
>   File "/data/go_dl/resources/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 925, in format
>     return fmt.format(record)
>   File "/data/go_dl/resources/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 664, in format
>     record.message = record.getMessage()
>   File "/data/go_dl/resources/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 369, in getMessage
>     msg = msg % self.args
> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
> Call stack:
>   File "renameFiles_v2.py", line 46, in <module>
>     logging.info("rowListValue :",rowListValue)
> Message: 'rowListValue :'
> Arguments: ('/data/go_dl/resources/CMM/NOKIA_CMM_MST_00001.DAT\n',)
> --- Logging error ---
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/data/go_dl/resources/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1081, in emit
>     msg = self.format(record)
>   File "/data/go_dl/resources/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 925, in format
>     return fmt.format(record)
>   File "/data/go_dl/resources/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 664, in format
>     record.message = record.getMessage()
>   File "/data/go_dl/resources/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 369, in getMessage
>     msg = msg % self.args
> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
> Call stack:
>   File "renameFiles_v2.py", line 46, in <module>
>     logging.info("rowListValue :",rowListValue)
> Message: 'rowListValue :'
> Arguments: ('/data/go_dl/resources/CMM/NOKIA_CMM_MST_00002.DAT\n',)
> --- Logging error ---
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/data/go_dl/resources/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1081, in emit
>     msg = self.format(record)
>   File "/data/go_dl/resources/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 925, in format
>     return fmt.format(record)
>   File "/data/go_dl/resources/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 664, in format
>     record.message = record.getMessage()
>   File "/data/go_dl/resources/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 369, in getMessage
>     msg = msg % self.args
> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
> Call stack:
>   File "renameFiles_v2.py", line 46, in <module>
>     logging.info("rowListValue :",rowListValue)
> Message: 'rowListValue :'
> Arguments: ('/data/go_dl/resources/CMM/NOKIA_CMM_MST_00003.DAT',)
> ```

But the log file created by the process is saving the information accordingly.

What am I doing wrong to have the error being printed on the screen?

Answer (score 3):

well, basically what I did to solve the problem was change the line below :

from:

```
logging.info("rowListValue :",rowListValue)
```

to:

```
logging.info("rowListValue :"+rowListValue)
```

In this part of the code :

```
try:
    with open(fileList,"r") as arq:
        for rowListValue  in arq.readlines():
            logging.info("rowListValue :",rowListValue)
```

Thanks all